# ReSetting jdk Installation to prevent installation issue

Tags: java, installation

i am having a problem, today i started jdk installation and my pc's battery went down/shut down, and when i restarted it it says "FINISH the current installation before you start another", how can i reset it?

Comment: It sounds like you just resumed the computer from sleep/hibernate after the battery triggered it. Try restarting the computer manually and it should work.

Comment: i did, i did everything, i even cleared my caches, but it still does the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it guys, it is in the folder `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\LocalLow\Sun` folder.

delete the folder or a file i don't remember it's name, but anyways delete the file and you will be able to install JDK again

Answer (score 0):

I'm, not 100% sure but try deleting all the created JDK files including the once in temp folders and AppData, or if that's too much work try IObit Uninstaller

Comment: i will try it, or else i will try IObit uninstaller